# How can I solve the linear equation xA=x which A is nonsquare

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a linear equation xA=b in which

```
A=[1/4   1/4   0    1/2
   1/3   1/3   1/3  0
   0     1/4   1/2  1/4
   1/2   0     1/4  1/4]
```

and

```
x=[x1 x2 x3 x4]
```

and `b=[x1 x2 x3 x4]`

1. How can I obtain the solution as

   x2=3/4 x1
      x3=x1
      x4=x1
2. Add more condition that is `x1+x2+x3+x4=1`. How can I find the solution of `x1=4/15...`

I want to use MATLAB to solve 2 above problems? Could you suggest to me the MATLAB code to do it? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried matrix divide? `/` or `\\`

Comment: Can it solve the first issue?

Comment: Wait... if `x=[x1;x2;x3;x4]` and `b=[x1;x2;x3;x4]` then there is only one `A` that can solve `Ax=b` which is the identity matrix...

Comment: Yes. x=b. If only have 4 equations, we only find the relationship between x1,x2...It is first issue. For second issue, I will add more condition as sum(x)=1. It will give exactly solution

Comment: It is one part "Stationary distribution relation to eigenvectors and simplices" in the link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain

Comment: you will get the [least squares solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29#The_general_problem) with the pseudo-inverse matrix `(A^TA)^-1`

Comment: You are trying to find the eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue of 1, use `eig`, don't solve a matrix problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a typical least squares problem. If you think of `b` being `I*b` and move it to the left hand side you have `(A-I)*x=0` and the sum can be represented as a row vector of ones times x must equal 1.

Combine them and you get

```
>> [A-eye(4);ones(1,4)]\[zeros(4,1);1]
ans =
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
```

Check whether this is a solution

```
>> A*ans
ans =
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
    0.2500
```

For the equation `xA = y` you can simply use the transpose of matrix `A`

```
>> [A'-eye(4);ones(1,4)]\[zeros(4,1);1]
ans =
    0.2667
    0.2000
    0.2667
    0.2667
>> A'*ans
ans =
    0.2667
    0.2000
    0.2667
    0.2667
```

which matches your solution

---

you can also enforce a value of the unknowns by again as another row. Say `x=4/15` via

```
[A'-eye(4);ones(1,4);eye(4,1)']\[zeros(4,1);1;4/15]
```

Comment: My solution is x1=4/15; x2=3/15; x3=4/15; x4=4/15. Could you check it again?

Comment: it must be xA=x, instead of Ax=x. Could you update your solution?

Comment: Thank percusse. How about the first issue?

Comment: @user3051460 In this case, the matrix is full rank so the solution is unique anyways. Can you elaborate what you mean by the first issuE ?

Comment: In this case, I assueme that A is not full rank. How can i solve x

Comment: @user3051460 Added an option

Answer (score 1):

```
clc
clear all
A      = sym('a%d%d',      [4 4], 'real');
x      = sym('x%d%d',      [4 1], 'real');
B      = sym('b%d%d',      [4 1], 'real');

rank(A)
A(4,:) = 2*A(1,:)
B(4) = 2*B(1)

%confirm rank deficiency
rank(A)


% equaion system is A*x==B
%Solve case 1:
sol1= solve(A*x==B, [x(2), x(3), x(4)])

%solve case 2:
sol2 = solve([A*x==B, x(1)+x(2)+x(3)+x(4)==1], [x(1) x(2), x(3), x(4)])
```

Comment: Thanks, However, I was wrong. it must be xA=x, instead of Ax=x. Could you update your solution